# How to choose an orm framework in my ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My task is to develop a large web application for my company. But I have no ideas to choose an orm ,my questions below:

1. Entity Framework or Nhibernate?
2. If Entity Framework?code first or db first?

Comment: Since you don't have an opinion, pick one. Flip a coin.

Comment: Start introductory work on both.  Determine which better fits the needs of the system, or is more intuitive to use, etc.  It's better to make a choice after trying both than to just guess.  You might find entirely other options work just as well, too.  Those aren't the only two.

Answer (score 0):

Use Dapper. Because StackExchange.